# Navigation Drawer icon not shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am using Custom Action bar. For which the code i am using is -

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_home_action_bar);
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
            R.color.color_dark_blue)));
```

but when I use this code to customise my action bar, navigation drawer icon is not shown. When I comment these lines it is perfectly shown but then I cannot customise my action bar.How can i achieve both?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I used

```
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM |  ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```

instead of

```
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```